# Permission denied on Chromebook even with sudo

Tags: bash, mount, sudo, chromebook

When I compile my C++ code on my Chromebook's shell, I get the error `bash: ./a.out: Permission denied`. This happens even when I run with sudo: `sudo: unable to execute ./a.out: Permission denied`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the filesystem was mounted with the `noexec` flag, probably for security reasons. To get around this,

1. Run `sudo mount -o remount,rw -o exec PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE`, where PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE is the directory where you're trying to execute the file.
2. If you get an error like `mount: /home/chronos/user/Downloads not mounted or bad option`, remove the last directory from the command (in this case /Downloads) and try again. Keep removing until it works.
3. If you get an error like `When remounting eCryptfs, you need to pass the mount utility the -i parameter to avoid calling the mount helper`, run `sudo mount -o remount,rw -io exec PATH/TO/YOUR/`.

You should now be able to run the file.