# mount operation not permitted in ChromeOS developer mode

Tags: debian, mount, iso-image, google-chrome-os, texlive

I want to install [texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) on my Chromebook by enabling the builtin [developer mode](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en) of ChromeOS, which runs debian on a virtual machine. So, I downloaded the ISO file of texlive from [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html). The problem is that I am unable to mount the ISO file. Whenever I try to run

```
sudo mount -o loop texlive.iso /home/aman/iso_mount
```

in the terminal, it outputs the following:

```
mount: /home/aman/iso_mount: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

I also tried to install [furiusisomount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furius_ISO_Mount) which also did not work. The installation is failing.

As suggested by @mashuptwice I also tried

```
sudo mount -v ./texlive.iso /home/aman/iso_mount
```

It is still not working. The output is

```
mount: /home/aman/iso_mount: permission denied.
```

Comment: Could you run `sudo mount -v ./texlive.iso /home/aman/iso_mount` and edit your question with the output? Note that the `-o loop` argument shoudn't be necessary in recent versions of mount.
Also make sure that the directory `/home/aman/iso_mount` exists.

Comment: @mashuptwice I have updated the question. It is still not working. The directory exists.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1264615/permission-denied-on-chromebook-even-with-sudo

Comment: @mashuptwice It is still not working. It says 'bad usage'